# How to redraw correctly bargraphview using the graph view library for Android?

Tags: android, android-graphview

For some reason (that I can develop if you want/need) I have to redraw all the chart periodically. So, I use removeAllSeries then addSeries, plus removeAllViews then addView. It works but the problem is that addView adds the view not by simply refreshing all pixels of the tablet but with a sort of "animation" that puts firstly the View a little bit (2 or 3 pixels) shifted to the right and then it takes the right place. The consequence is that, everytime I redraw my graph, it looks as if there is a "vibration" (it's not fluid).

Do anyone have some issue? Could this undesired "animation" be related to how the addView method is done?

Comment: P.S. : Is there a simple way to redraw only the rectangles (bars) of the graph ? What I want to do is to change dynamically the color (style) of the graph and redraw it. What I do now is redrawing all the graph. But I think it could be better to redraw only the bars. I tried to modify the source code of GraphView library but not successfully for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are three ways:

1. redrawAll() method. Maybe it is protected, but you can overwrite and
   make it public
2. change the data in series (appendData or resetData). The Graph will
   automatically rerender.
3. removeAllSeries + add new series. No need to call
   removeAllViews/addView. Take a look at the GraphViews-Demos project,
   there is an example about that.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer ! I actually just simply overrided the ValueDependentColor() method directly in my main activity. The color depends on a timer. So, when I reset data after x seconds the graph rerenders as you said in your "2."